# Apply custom function to a column in data frame if the column value is not equal to nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Maybe Python geniuses can help me here-
So I have a machine learning algorithm where I am obtaining my classifier like :

```
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

To get it to predict I simply write

```
print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["I am happy today"])))
```

and it gives me back the Category in which this sentence falls.
Now I want to use this clf to predict results for me for a column. I have another data frame dfnew which consists of 2 columns, and the second column with the header 'Additional Information' has the strings that I need to pass to clf.predict.
But this columns has blank values as in the figure below
[image]
How do I pass this 'additional Information' column to clf.predict() such that it skips the nan ones and only predicts for strings present. At best, I would want the results to be added in the same data frame dfnew in the third column.

Any help or guidance would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is the `apply` method. Simply:

```
def classify_when_possible(add_info):
    if add_info is None:
        return None
    else:
        return clf.predict(count_vect.transform([add_info]))

#if you want it to be added to your dataframe
dfnew['third column'] = dfnew.apply(lambda row: classify_when_possible(row['Additional Information']), axis=1)
```

Note: there's many ways to use apply, some are more optimized depending on use case.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I know of the apply function but I am still a bit rusty in the implementation of it and was getting errors when I tried myself.